# Passive form of Never tell a lie

Tags: passive-voice

What is the passive form of 'Never tell a lie'.

> a. Let a lie never be told.
>   b. Let not a lie ever be told.

Comment: Neither of those is passive. They are both imperatives, similar to the original. In fact, I don't think it's possible to have a passively phrased imperative.

Comment: A lie must never be told

Comment: @JasonBassford "Don't be seen" --> passive imperative

Comment: @eques That's just an elided form of *you must be sure that you are not seen*.

Comment: @Juhasz Yes, that's good.

Comment: @JasonBassford No, it's a passive imperative. Elision is specifically the omission of components, not the changing of them. Using "be" instead of "are" is already evidence that it is imperative (or subjunctive) rather than the indicative in your example. Furthermore, other languages (e.g. Spanish and Latin) do have passive imperative constructions.

Comment: @JasonBassford it is substantively similar in meaning, but that doesn't make one a form of the other. "Be here on time" is not an elided form of "You must be here on time" nor is "Don't shout" for "You must not shout"

Comment: @eques (*You must ensure that you) don't be seen.*

Comment: You don't use do-support in negative subjunctive that clauses. "I ask that he not late". And I'm also not sure it works with "ensure" anyways; it sounds especially out to use it with the same subject (i.e. "You must ensure to not be seen" would be more natural).

Comment: My other examples show why your "elision" argument is illogical

Comment: @eques  Fine, if you want to nit pick the syntax. *Do (you ensure that you) not be seen*. The point is that an imperative includes a command to a subject (implicit or explicit) to do or not do something.

Comment: Passive imperatives are a grammatical construct. Your argument for their supposed non-existence is essentially special pleading since the same expansions can apply to active imperatives. And even as you hint at, there still is a command to do or not do something (negative passives seem more common), namely to allow/prevent the action from occurring to the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jason Bassford mentions, an *imperative* like "Don't do X" can not be phrased in the passive voice -- but you can certainly rewrite the imperative to *sound* more passive.

With that in mind: Both of your answers are valid, if somewhat formal.  Neither is passive, since you've just changed one active verb (*tell*) with another active verb (*let*), but the underlying command does sound more passive.

Some other possible variations, all of which are formal (and somewhat archaic):

> Never let a lie be told
>
> Never should a lie be told
>
> Let not a lie be told
>
> Let no lies be told

Answer (score 2):

You are advised not to tell a lie ever.